# Using 'someone's goodness' as 'my goodness'

Tags: word-usage, interjections

An interjection *'oh my goodness!'* is quite known to us. It talks **about** *surprises*.

Say -

> [My goodness, it's warm in here!](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/goodness_1)

Now, I was like using the same expression for a third person.

Say -

> To *her goodness*, it was warm in there!

Is it possible?

Limitations of search engines show results of goodness as a **noun**. The context is **entirely different** It is **not about** *surprises*.

> *Her goodness* and kindness is praise worthy.

That's the reason, I'm not able to find the usage I want from the original expression.

If *'my x'* is possible, it should be possible with *'his x'* and *'her x'* also! What say?

Answer (score 4):

As this is about the language and not about religion:

An interjection like "my goodness" is something that is typically *said*, not *written* or if written, to represent informal language or mimic the spoken word, but not used in formal texts.

> My goodness, it is warm here!

If you describe another person using it, you would ***quote*** this person, not use reported speech, so no need to fiddle with adjusting the possessive.

> "My goodness, it is warm here!", Sally exclaimed.

Therefore do not write something like

> <del>Sally's goodness, it was warm!
>
>   To her goodness, it was warm!</del>

Comment: +1 for that suggestion of 'quoting' that I did not think of. Do you see that 'okay' if spoken? I mean 'to her goodness....'?

Comment: No. It is a "personal" statement. "My goodness" - look at it as a fixed phrase.

Comment: You could say "To her surprise, it was warm in there," but as Stephie says, "My goodness" is a fixed phrase, and it's used as an interjection.  If Sally was a bit less polite, she could have said, "Bloody hell, it's warm in here" instead.

Answer (score 0):

***My goodness*** is an euphemism invented in order hypocritically to avoid using the name of Our Lord in vain. In other words, it stands for "Oh my God!" Which is one of the most disgusting ways to defy the Third Commandment.

Variations on the same theme include "By Jove!", "Goodness me!", "Heavens!", "Gosh!" etc. The medieval list included many more of them ("Zounds!" stood for "God's Wounds," to pick one at random, and "S'blood!", to pick another, stood for "Christ's Blood!").

Since one is never sure that his or her God is necessarily the other party's God (i.e. that they, too, believe in Him), one's limited to using "my."

Practicing Christians, Jews and Muslims should avoid interjections of this sort like a plague. Why very few priests make an effort to explain the importance of the Third Commandment to their parishioners is a mystery.

Comment: So, *my goodness* is always in fear and strange astonishment? Never in a good way?

Comment: @MaulikV, putting Ricky's sensitivities aside, the interjection can be used both ways.

Comment: @MaulikV: Those are two separate issues. The interjection, like any other interjection, is a reflection of any surge of feelings. _Using_ this particular interjection is uncouth no matter how many people, show producers, and moviemakers think it's okay.

Comment: @MaulikV, **Oh my G(o)od(ness)!" can be used in the same way as the text acronym **OMG** would be used.  To clarify any ambiguity (at)Ricky is saying "Oh my G-d" should never be used.